# Spring MVC, JSP - Required boolean parameter 'guest' is not present

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do something with permissions for guest and user, and I did something, but It doesn't work, error which is in title appears.

/home and /logged/home are using the same jsp

I want in order to "register" and "log in" won't display for logged users

MainController:

```
@Controller  
public class MainController {

DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

@RequestMapping(value = "/home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView HomePage(@RequestParam boolean guest) {

    User user = new User();
    user.setGuest(guest);
    user.isGuest();

    ModelAndView main = new ModelAndView("Main");

    return main;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/logged/home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView homePageforUsers(@RequestParam boolean loggeduser) {

    User user = new User();
    user.setUser(loggeduser);
    user.isUser();

    ModelAndView main = new ModelAndView("Main");

    return main;

}
```

Main.jsp:

```
<c:if test="${user.isUser()}">
<div class="cart">
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/cart.html"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> Cart </a>
        <div class="logout">
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/home.html"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> Log out </a>
</div>
</div>
</c:if>

<c:if test ="${user.isGuest()}">
<div class="register">
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/registration.html"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> Register </a>
</div>
<div class="login">
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/login.html"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> Log in </a>
</div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/home.html"
```

This part triggers the call to your `HomePage` controller and there is no `guest` query parameter available in it, hence Spring MVC complains about absence of that required parameter.

By default parameters that annotated with `RequestParam` are **Required**. So, you either should make them optional, for example like this:

```
@RequestParam(required=false) boolean guest
```

or provide some sensible default value for them, like following:

```
@RequestParam(defaultValue="false") boolean guest
```

If you can't use the proposed solutions, provide those mandatory parameters in every request, in your case that would be something like:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/home.html?guest=false"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> Log out </a>
```

Comment: I solved it already with model.addAttribute and inject value in jsp, but thank you :)